How can I scale this section correctly from a Blue print
I'm practising using a blue print of a Boeing airplane. The side of the mesh seems correctly following the lines.
When I try to expand the mesh from the top to follow the lines of the airplane, when I see it from the side view again, the mesh is out of the blue print lines.
How can I fix this?





i would try using S X e.g. to just scale along the x axis and don't destroy the "right" z-axis (as example to your first image) maybe even with proportional editing?

That was it, I had to scale as you implied S X axis, I was making the mistake just scaling S that's why it was going out of the line art. I'm currently learning how to model basic shapes using Blue print line art. Thanks for your help.

You can also press S -> Shift + (XYZ AXIS) to scale on all but the specified axis. So in this example S->Shift+X to scale on all but the X axis.

you can press S X (YZ) to scale just on one axis.
or
S Shift-X (YZ) to scale just on all axis except x (yz)
